# help me please?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Напишите программу, которая проверяет, что для заданного четырехзначного числа выполняется следующее соотношение: сумма первой и последней цифр равна разности второй и третьей цифр.

Формат входных данных
На вход программе подаётся одно целое положительное четырёхзначное число.

Формат выходных данных
Программа должна вывести «ДА», если соотношение выполняется, и «НЕТ» — если не выполняется.

Sample Input 1:

1614
Sample Output 1:

ДА
Sample Input 2:

1234
Sample Output 2:

НЕТ

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while True:
    digit = input('Sample input: ')

    if not digit:
        break

    [a, b, c, d] = map(int, list(digit))

    if a + d == b - c:
        print('Yes')

    else:
        print('No')
```